# Batch file to share Folder

Tags: batch-file, networking, directory, sharing

I need to create a folder and share it at multiple customer sites. The folder will be on a local PC at the site and I want to create a batch file for this. The issue I have is the copier that I am creating the share for is already setup to scan to the share folder `\\COMPUTERNAME\Scans` but when I create the batch file to share the foler it puts the network share name twice `\\COMPUTERNAME\COMPUTERNAME\Scans`, I need to figure out how to get rid of one of the computer names using the batch file. Below is the commands I am using with my batch file. Any suggestions?

```
mkdir "C:\Scans\"

Net Share %COMPUTERNAME%=C:\Scans

Cacls C:\Scans /e /r Everyone

Cacls C:\Scans /e /g Everyone:F
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the share name :

> NET SHARE sharename=drive:path /REMARK:"text" [/CACHE:Manual |
>   Automatic | No ]

please try

```
Net Share SCANS=C:\Scans
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that is exactly what the issue is, I had a variable of %computername% so that is why it was showing up twice. I removed that variable and replace with scans and works correctly now.  Thanks!!!!!